# Nexmo SMS with visual foxpro

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-foxpro, foxpro, vonage

I am unable to send Nexmo-SMS with  foxpro application. Application was working till January 2017 after that it stopped working. Given below is  my application. It gives the error message 404. Kindly guide me if there is correction require the program.

---

```
mob = '39829374'

mmessage = 'Hi'

username='username'

pwd='password'

mmob1 =ALLTRIM(mmob )

MMOB = '00973'+ALLTRIM(mmob )


From='AMA Motors' 

to = '&mmob'

lcMessage=mmessage

lcNexmo = Textmerge("http://rest.nexmo.com/sms/xml?username=<< m.username >>|password=<< m.pwd >>|from=<< m.from >>|to=<< m.to >>|text=<< m.lcMessage >>")

lcNexmo = Chrtran(m.lcNexmo, '|', Chr(38))

* Message parameters ready


Local loXmlHttp As "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"

loXmlHttp = Newobject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" )


loXmlHttp.Open( "POST" , m.lcNexmo, .F. )

loXmlHttp.Send( )


If loXmlHttp.Status = 200

    lcXML = 
StrExtract(loXmlHttp.responsetext,'<messages','</messages>',1,1+4)

    XMLToCursor(m.lcXML,'myresult')

*   browse

Else

    MessageBox( Textmerge( "An error occurred in SMS. Status <<loXmlHttp.STATUS>> (<<loXmlHttp.statustext>>)." ) )

Endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think that your code has never worked. Probably you put here a version that wouldn't work at all. Anyway, I think the problem is that you are not using https. I edited your code a bit and sent 3 messages (sorry for wasting your tokens):

```
NexmoKey    = '1b37ecc8'
NexmoSecret = 'df183c07'
NexmoNumber = 'AMA Motors'

mob = '39829374'
mmessage = 'Hi'
MMOB = '00973'+ALLTRIM(m.mob )


to = m.mmob
lcMessage = m.mmessage

nexmoURL = Textmerge(;
    "https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/xml?"+;
    "username=<< m.NexmoKey >>|"+;
    "password=<< m.NexmoSecret >>|"+;
    "from=<< m.NexmoNumber >>")

TrySendTTS(m.to,m.lcMessage, m.NexmoUrl)

Procedure TrySendTTS(tcPhone,tcMessage, tcNexmoUrl)
    tcMessage = Strtran(m.tcMessage, '%0A', '%0D%0A')
    lcUrl = Chrtran(;
        Textmerge("<< m.tcNexmoUrl >>|to=<< m.tcPhone >>|text=<< m.tcMessage >>"), '|', Chr(38))

    Local loXmlHttp As "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"
    loXmlHttp = Newobject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" )

    loXmlHttp.Open( "POST" , m.lcUrl, .F. )
*   loXmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    loXmlHttp.Send( )

    ? loXmlHttp.Status = 200
    ? loXmlHttp.responsetext

Endproc
```

And this is the response I got to the latest send:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<mt-submission-response>
    <messages count='1'>
        <message>
            <to>97339829374</to>
            <messageId>0B00000044C5B1ED</messageId>
            <status>0</status>
            <remainingBalance>6.23650000</remainingBalance>
            <messagePrice>0.01740000</messagePrice>
            <network>42601</network>
        </message>
    </messages>
</mt-submission-response>
```